# Stream issue with StreamProvider

Tags: flutter-provider

I'm using StreamBuilder to listen to changes in user authentication and then StreamProvider to fetch data from Firestore while constantly listening to changes in user documents. I sometimes got occasional crashes for a small percentage of users, but lately, this number has risen.

This is the crash from Crashlytics:
`Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: An exception was throw by _MapStream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, UserData> listened by at FirebaseCrashlytics.recordError(firebase_crashlytics.dart:119) at FirebaseCrashlytics.recordFlutterError(firebase_crashlytics.dart:145) at FlutterError.reportError(assertions.dart:1185) at _streamStartListening.<fn>.<fn>(async_provider.dart:32)`

**This is my code:**

```
runApp(
    StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return StreamProvider<UserData>.value(
            value: getUserData(snapshot.data?.uid),
            initialData: UserData(),
            child: Phoenix(child: MyApp(flavorSettings, snapshot)));
      },
    ),
  );
}

Stream<UserData> getUserData(String? uid) {
  if (uid != null) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map((doc) {
      final data = doc.data();
      if (data != null) {
        return UserData.fromJson(data);
      } else {
        return UserData();
      }
    });
  }
  return Stream<UserData>.value(UserData());
}
```

I want to use:

`final data = Provider.of<UserData>(context, listen: false);`

In the entire app get the newest version of UserData while still being sure that the user is authenticated.